# valgrind strange conditional jump messages before program starts

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

Before my program even starts I am receiving uninitialized value messages that reference function calls that are not in my program.  I am confused as to why I am receiving these messages and how I can clean them up?

```
==24266== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24266==    at 0x809098A: __linkin_atfork (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x80919EB: _dl_non_dynamic_init (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x80921B1: __libc_init_first (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x805F60B: (below main) (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==  Uninitialised value was created
==24266==    at 0x8091662: _dl_sysinfo_int80 (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x80BE31F: brk (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x808DE99: sbrk (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x805F96B: __libc_setup_tls (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x805FB66: __pthread_initialize_minimal (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
==24266==    by 0x805F5A3: (below main) (in /home/mbarry/workspace/datapup/src/plugin)
```

Comment: Most likely they are through global objects which get created before execution of your program begins.Are you creating any global objects of library types?

Comment: http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/12146/5877/

Comment: I removed pthread.h and all references to pthread out and I still get the same message.  I do have a lot of global variables.

Comment: Assuming you use `gdb`: Did you you also remove the `-pthread` option from the build command(s)?

Comment: yea im no longer linking pthread.  I have isolated it down to the global variables. I am going to go through them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

It was incorrect use of -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -static flags in my gcc makefile causing the memory issue.